# A query "SELECT extract date + count" doesn't work (node.js+oracle sql)

Tags: node.js, oracle

May be someone could help me.
My query works inside oracle developer, but it doesn't when I try to reside it on server side. My server side is built with node.js.

> The error is  ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

So this version works(from oracle sql developer):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PUBLICATIONS.PUBLICATION_DATE), COUNT(PUBLICATIONS.PUBLICATION_ID)
FROM PUBLICATIONS
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PUBLICATIONS.PUBLICATION_DATE)
```

The result is table where: in first column locates years, in second locates: total amount of publications corresponding to year.

But this doesn't work (request from server):

```
connection.execute(
    "SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PUBLICATIONS.PUBLICATION_DATE), COUNT(PUBLICATIONS.PUBLICATION_ID)"+
    "FROM PUBLICATIONS PU"+
    "GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PU.PUBLICATION_DATE)",
    [], { maxRows: 10 },
    function(err, result){
        if (err) { console.error(Err_sql,err.message); return; }
        console.log(Sql_ans,result.rows);
    });
```

Also I checked more simple request, and it works:

```
connection.execute(
            "SELECT Title " +
            "FROM Title " +
            "WHERE Title.title_id = :id",
            [111], { maxRows: 10 }, // bind value for :id 
            function(err, result){
                if (err) { console.error(Err_sql,err.message); return; }
                console.log(Sql_ans,result.rows);
            });
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems that you need blanks in the end/begining of your query strings

Comment: Thank you very much! So easy! =) It works =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing some white space (right hand side of each line) that would be needed for the query to be valid.

Try this:

```
connection.execute(
    "SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PUBLICATIONS.PUBLICATION_DATE), COUNT(PUBLICATIONS.PUBLICATION_ID) "+
    "FROM PUBLICATIONS PU "+
    "GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PU.PUBLICATION_DATE)",
    [], { maxRows: 10 },
    function(err, result){
        if (err) { console.error(Err_sql,err.message); return; }
        console.log(Sql_ans,result.rows);
    }
);
```